# Cypress viewport doesn't accurately reflect the device that's specified

Tags: cypress, viewport

While attempting to test scripts using either cy.viewport('iphone-x') or cy.viewport(375,812), both render the site the same (incorrectly) but differently than if I open Chrome, go to devtools and specify the same device there. I'm relatively new to Cypress but I haven't been able to figure out why this happens or how to get Cypress to render the website correctly.

**Using Devtools**
[image: Using Devtools]

**Using Cypress**
[image: Using Cypress]

Comment: Follow-up: I tried adding the user agent thinking that might trick it, but no such luck. 

  beforeEach('Login', function() {
    cy.viewport('iphone-x')
          onBeforeLoad: win => {
              Object.defineProperty(win.navigator, 'userAgent', {
                  value: 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 12_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/69.0.3497.105 Mobile/15E148 Safari/605.1',
              });
          },

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like this might actually be a code issue within the app. Using devtools, if I inspect the white space it shows `height:auto`. De-selecting this within devtools makes the screen look like it does when viewing it in Cypress using a mobile viewport. I've logged a bug with my app's development team.